# Declare a Map<String, Object> as a scoped variable cause problem

Tags: spring-mvc

When I declare a Map<String, Object> scoped variable in my SpringMVC project as below:

```
    @Bean
    @SessionScope
    public Map<String, Object> allProjects() {
        return new TreeMap<>();
    }
```

It is weird that it contains many unexpected things even I didn't put anything into it. Just like it is the whole session scope. It will not happen if I declare it as Map<String, String>. Is there any formal statement in document talked about this?